# Getting multiple tables from HTML using Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am trying to scrape data from multiple tables on this website: http://www.national-autograss.co.uk/march.htm

I need to keep the table data together with their respective dates located in h2 so I would like a way to do the following:

- Find first date header h2
- Extract table data beneath h2 (can be multiple tables)
- Move on to next header and extract tables etc

I have written code to extract all parts separately but I do not know how to extract the data so that it stays with the relevant date header.

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated. The code I am starting with is below but like I said all it is doing is iterating through the data.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.national-autograss.co.uk/march.htm").get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Elements elementsTable1 = doc.select("#table1"); 
        Elements elementsTable2 = doc.select("#table2");
        Elements dateElements = doc.select("h2");

        for (int i = 0; i < dateElements.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(dateElements.get(i).text());
            System.out.println(elementsTable1.get(i).text());
            System.out.println(elementsTable2.get(i).text());

        }

}
}
```

Comment: If I were you I would create a class that contains the neccessary variables. Then create a list with instances of this class, which can later be used :)

Comment: I understand the logic of that but my problem is that all of the tables in the html source are labelled as either table1 or table2. How would I get the fitrst date header and then only the tables underneath that header, i.e not getting tables from further down the document etc.

Comment: Ah! I posted as answer instead since my answer was too long for a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the values that you want are stored inside `<tr>`'s in a table where in every table the first child is a `<h2>`.

```
<table align="center"><col width="200"><col width="150"><col width="100"><col width="120"><col width="330"><col width="300">
        <h2>Sunday 30 March</h2>
        <tr id="table1">
            <td><b>Club</b></td>
            <td><b>Venue</b></td>
            <td><b>Start Time</b></td>
            <td><b>Meeting Type</b></td>
            <td><b>Number of Days for Meeting</b></td>
            <td><b>Notes</b></td>

        </tr>
        <tr id="table2">
            <td>Evesham</td>
            <td>Dodwell</td>
            <td>11:00am</td>
            <td>RO</td>
            <td>Single Days Racing</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

My suggestion is that you search for all tables, when first child is a `h2` you do something with the rest of its children:

```
Elements tables = doc.select("table");
for(Element table : tables) {
    if(table.child(0).tagName().equals("h2")) {
        Elements children = table.children()
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT** : You want to remove all `<col>` before the `<h2>` as they will appear before it (did not notice this before):

```
for(Element element : doc.select("col"))
{
    element.remove();
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Starting to get to where I want to be with it now!